# Best practices for using SCD component in Talend

Tags: talend, scd, scd2

I am using tPostgresqlSCD. 
The performance is really slow. It inserts 1 row per second or even slower. 
Is there anyway to increase the peformance of it?
I tried 'Use memory saving modes'. Which makes it even slower. 
I am inserting around 9000 rows in a 5 million rows dimension. 
I even have much bigger dimensions also. 
How is it scalable?

Comment: you can try to see if  you can do scd using your own logic and other components and not use out of box scd component ..that way you can have better control over things.

Comment: I understand that. But still I was wondering there might be a way to improve this component. 2 rows per second insert is not how it should work anyway

Comment: that component is garbage, we implemented our own version in a routine that works with dynamic schemas as well